# Exchange data between Python and Perl sockets

Tags: python, perl, sockets, python-3.x

My colleague wrote a simple server on Perl, which listening port and waits for message, and then sends a response:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


use strict;
use IO::Select;
use IO::Socket::INET;

use constant SIZE => 1024;
use constant EOL => "\x0D\x0A";

my %user_input;

if(scalar @ARGV < 2)
{
die "Usage: server.pl ip port\n";
}

my ($serv_ip, $serv_port) = @ARGV;

my $socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(LocalAddr => $serv_ip, LocalPort => $serv_port, Listen => 20, Proto => 'tcp', Reuse => 1) or die $!;
my $select = IO::Select->new($socket) or die $!;

print "Started\n";

while(1)
      {
        my @r = $select->can_read;
        my @w = $select->can_write(.1);

      for my $handle (@r) {
                  if($handle eq $socket) {
                      my $connect = $socket->accept();
                      $select->add($connect);
                                          }
                      else {
                          my $user_input;
                          while(sysread $handle, $_, SIZE) {
                                  $user_input .= $_;
                                  last if $_ =~ /\x0A/ or length $user_input >= SIZE;
                                                        }
                                  printf ("Input:$user_input\n");
                                    if(length $user_input > 0) {
                                      $user_input = handle_request($user_input, $handle);
                                          if($user_input) {
                                             printf("Output:$user_input\n");
                                            syswrite $_, $user_input, SIZE for @w;
                                                          }
                                                } else {
                                             $select->remove($handle);
                                             close $handle;
                                                        }
                            }
                         }
        }

##################
sub handle_request
{
  my ($user_input, $handle) = @_;

my $error_begin = "Hello world!";
$error_begin .= EOL;

return $error_begin;
}
```

Don't ask. I do not understand at Pearl and fear him.

I wrote a simple script on Python 3 that sends a message and waits for response:

```
import socket
import json

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(2)
s.connect(('host', 9999))
data = 'message'
s.sendall(data.encode())

data = s.recv(1024)
print(data)

s.close()
```

When I run it raise the exception:

```
data = s.recv(1024)
socket.timeout: timed out
```

This means that my request comes, and the response not. But my colleague sees my requests on his server. At the same time, I successfully commit session with my own server on Python, with similar assignment. Moreover, I can send message and receive answers via telnet with my colleague's server. I suspect that there are some differences in the default sockets settings in Python and Perl.
Any idea what could be the problem?

UPD:
perl 5.20.1
python 3.4.2

Comment: What does the perl code look like?

Comment: What are the query specifications? Do the server waits for a given message length? Is the message formatted in a specific way? Cause at the moment, I do not really see how the server would know when to send a response to you.

Comment: Adding the perl script would help.

Comment: I asked them from colleague. Waiting.

Comment: Check the data movement with a third tool (tcpdump)! If the data comes, you need to debug only the receiver side. If it doesn't, you need to debug only the sender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O! I hate this! Initially on the server side was a mistake giving the same effect. But while it corrected, I had forgotten that the server is waiting for \n to complete the request.